# Can I make a HTTPS request or HTTP/2 request using Boost.Asio and Boost.Beast libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am planning to build a small crawler in C++ for my projects. I chose the `Boost.Asio` library to achieve networking functionality. But then, I came across `Boost.Beast` library and I am confused as of which library to use. I have 2 doubts:

**Question 1:**

Does `Boost.Asio` support `HTTPS` and `HTTP/2` connections?

**Question 2:**

What is the difference between `Boost.Asio` and `Boost.Beast`?

I have searched some documents and couldn't find useful information. Also, there are only a handful of articles about Boost libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: What part of this question can't you answer yourself by reading the publicly available boost documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Q1:

No, it will only do TCP for you.

Q2:

Asio:

> Boost.Asio is a cross-platform C++ library for network and low-level
>   I/O programming that provides developers with a consistent
>   asynchronous model using a modern C++ approach.
>   https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Beast:

> Beast is a C++ header-only library serving as a foundation for writing
>   interoperable networking libraries by providing low-level HTTP/1,
>   WebSocket, and networking protocol vocabulary types and algorithms
>   using the consistent asynchronous model of Boost.Asio.
>   https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html

In a nutshell, Asio is lower level, helps you with building asynchronous programs, helps with I/O and on the network side is limited to transport layer mostly. It has some support for SSL.

Beast is higher level and helps you when you need HTTP, Websockets etc. It is interoperable with Asio.

Comment: So, I wont be able to make any HTTPS request using `Boost.Asio`?

Comment: You can make HTTPS requests with Asio but you will need to serialize the HTTP message yourself, and parse the HTTP response from the server yourself. Beast does these things for you, so unless you have a really great reason for why you want to implement it yourself you are probably better off with using Beast.